# Django modelform value dropdown fields is object instead field of object

Tags: django, forms, django-forms

This the first time I use Django and I have a problem with dropdown boxes.

In my models.py, I have the following models:

```
class Country(models.Model):
countryID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
iso = models.CharField(max_length=2, null=False)
name = models.CharField(max_length=80, null=False)
nicename = models.CharField(max_length=80, null=False)
iso3 = models.CharField(max_length=3, null=False)
numcode = models.SmallIntegerField(null=False)
phonecode = models.SmallIntegerField(null=False)

class Address(models.Model):
addressID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False)
street = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False)
streetnumber = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False)
city = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False)
postalcode = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
country = models.ForeignKey(Country)
```

In my forms.py, I have my modelform:

```
class AddLocationForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Address
    fields = ('name','street','streetnumber','city','postalcode','country')
```

And views.py:

```
@login_required
def addlocation(request):
# Get the context from the request.
context = RequestContext(request)

# A HTTP POST?
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = AddLocationForm(request.POST)

    # Have we been provided with a valid form?
    if form.is_valid():
        # Save the new category to the database.

        form.save(commit=True)
        # Now call the index() view.
        # The user will be shown the homepage.
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        # The supplied form contained errors - just print them to the terminal.
        print(form.errors)
else:
    # If the request was not a POST, display the form to enter details.
    form = AddLocationForm()

# Bad form (or form details), no form supplied...
# Render the form with error messages (if any).
return render_to_response('accounts/addlocation.html', {'form': form}, context)
```

My database table "country" is populated with all the countries of the world.
Now when I fill in the form in the website, the values of the dropbdown box for country are "Country object" instead of the country's name like "Australia".

My question is how you can get the name of the countries as values of the dropdown box?

Answer (score 1):

You should define a `__unicode__` method on Country that returns `self.name`. (In Python 3, the method should be `__str__`.)

Comment: What if you have several dropdowns returning different columns from the Country model? With your suggestion everyone will return name